# Automatic paypal transfer to users without paypal payout

Tags: paypal, payment, payout

I want to transfer money from my paypal account to a certain number of users.
The issue is that paypal payout api doesn't work or isn't supported in my country.
Is there another service which I can do that with. Where I call using my server and automatically perform a transaction to a user's account.

I tried paypal payout but it wasn't working due to the non support.

Comment: In the live environment, Payouts is never enabled on any PayPal account by default. Did you apply for it? Probably the only solution, as Hyperwallet is for enterprise

Comment: couldn't do so as they have very selective conditions in France.

Comment: Either meet the conditions, use the manual Send Money action in the account, or use a different payment provider

Comment: know of a good other payment provider? @PrestonPHX